# Grab url from SFSafariViewController

Tags: swift, oauth

I have a little bit of an issue and yes, I have read the other SO posts on this.

I need to authorize with a third-party service using Google OAuth. The OAuth redirects to a page with a URL similar to this:

```
https://ab.cdef.gh.ij.lmno?code=dfim34958yjsisnijq0294tj
```

But because it doesn't redirect to `myappname://?code=dfim34958yjsisnijq0294tj`, I've been unable to get the code from that URL.

I've tried various OAuth libraries, but they all depend on `myappname://`

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

SFSafariViewController have limited options of exposing the URL, So this is not currently possible

Answer (score 0):

I guess you solved this in the mean time. But for others getting to this question:

Since iOS 11 the SFSafariViewController has the following delegate method:

```
func safariViewController(_ controller: SFSafariViewController, 
      initialLoadDidRedirectTo URL: URL)
```

and in Obj-C

```
- (void)safariViewController:(SFSafariViewController *)controller initialLoadDidRedirectToURL:(NSURL *)URL
```

This should exactly give you what you need: the URL including your access code.